# Using slash symbol beside filename?

Tags: url

is it possible to make my website accept slashes after file name and take the slash as the end of the url

like an example :

http://example.com/files/file.php

this will load normally

i want it to load by this too :
http://example.com/files/file.php/whateverhere

just but ignoring everything after .php so it wont give not found error

Comment: This will depend on what server you are using

Comment: Are you on apache? Do you have mod_rewrite installed?

Comment: i dont own the server, i just was hosted in it, tell me the method and i will try

Answer (score 0):

Add a .htaccess in your DocumentRoot with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase     /
    RewriteRule     ^(.*).php/(.*)$     $1.php  [L]
</IfModule>
```

This discards everything after `.php`. If you want to pass it as part of the GET query string, change the rule to something like:

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*).php/(.*)$     $1.php?foo=$2  [L]
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for trying to help,
I did what you said but i didn't work at first,
I googled that it doesn't work on godaddy hosting and one post said use this code :
Options +FollowSymLinks

I did and it worked but not that good
First it redirects me to the website main page instead of the file i requested
second it just allows the slash ( / ) to be written beside the file,
nothing after / is allowed .. like :
website.com/file.php/
this loads the website.com and not the file.php
and this :
website.com/file.php/whatever
this gives me an error :
No input file specified.